# i have used boolean concept to swap the text field in recycler items,

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, boolean

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

    static final String myTag = "DocsUpload";
    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    int clickcount=0;
    private Context mContext;
    List list = new ArrayList();
    Boolean signUpModeActive = true;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listItems, Context mContext) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view, mContext, listItems);
        return contactViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        RecyclerItem itemList = listItems.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(itemList.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView txtTitle;
        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public TextView txtDescription;
        public ImageView txtOptionDigit;
        ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listitems = new ArrayList<RecyclerItem>();

        Context ctx;

        public ContactViewHolder(View view, Context ctx, ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listitems) {
            super(view);
            this.listitems = listitems;
            this.ctx = ctx;
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxxml);
        }

        boolean m=false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickcount=clickcount+1;

            Log.e("count", String.valueOf(clickcount));
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            final RecyclerItem listitems = this.listitems.get(position);
            final String getname = listitems.getTitle();

            if (signUpModeActive=true) {

                signUpModeActive = false;
                listItems.get(position).setTitle("");
                listItems.get(position).setTitle(getname + " " +"absent");

            } else {

                signUpModeActive = true;
                listItems.get(position).setTitle("");
                listItems.get(position).setTitle(getname + " " +"present");
            }


            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    public void getsetadapt(String pos) {

        list.add(pos);
        Log.e("listdata", String.valueOf(list));


        for (int i=0;i < list.size();i++)
        {
            Log.i("Value "+i, String.valueOf(list.get(i)));

            i++;

        }
    }
```

when I click any list items it want add absent to existing text and if I click it again it want to replace absent  with present..can any one know where iam going wrong  ...and if run this code at my emulator it works and it is adding the text it is not replacing. For example the if I click student oviya its adding text absent near to oviya but if I click it again it is not replacing its is adding present next to that again and again

Answer (score 0):

Just change your adapter to the following adapter and it will work fine

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

static final String myTag = "DocsUpload";
ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
int clickcount = 0;
private Context mContext;
List list = new ArrayList();
Boolean signUpModeActive = true;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listItems, Context mContext) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_2, parent, false);

    ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view, mContext, listItems);
    return contactViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    RecyclerItem itemList = listItems.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(itemList.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}


public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtTitle;
    public CheckBox checkBox;
    public TextView txtDescription;
    public ImageView txtOptionDigit;
    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listitems = new ArrayList<RecyclerItem>();

    Context ctx;

    public ContactViewHolder(View view, Context ctx, ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listitems) {
        super(view);
        this.listitems = listitems;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxxml);
    }

    boolean m = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickcount = clickcount + 1;


        Log.e("count", String.valueOf(clickcount));
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        final RecyclerItem listitems = this.listitems.get(position);
        final String getname = listitems.getTitle().replace(" absent" , "").replace(" present" , "");

        if (signUpModeActive ) {

            signUpModeActive = false;
            listItems.get(position).setTitle(getname + " " + "absent");

        } else {

            signUpModeActive = true;
            listItems.get(position).setTitle(getname + " " + "present");
        }


        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

public void getsetadapt(String pos) {

    list.add(pos);
    Log.e("listdata", String.valueOf(list));


    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("Value " + i, String.valueOf(list.get(i)));

        i++;

    }
}
```

}

Actually the problem was in line

```
final RecyclerItem listitems = this.listitems.get(position);
        final String getname = listitems.getTitle();
```

you were setting text as

```
 listItems.get(position).setTitle(getname + " " + "absent");
```

OR

```
 listItems.get(position).setTitle(getname + " " + "present");
```

This will result as Name absent or Name present as result and will add a new absent or present to it

Comment: what should i want to change now? @Harsh Patel

Comment: ok got what you you have said ,,, give some time for checking

Comment: change your whole adapter as I have displayed @subashchandru

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems in your code.

**1**
First of all, your variables are not named correctly so it's very confusing. For example you use `listitems` and `listItems` which are almost exactly the same. Plus `listitems` is used twice for 2 different variables with the exact same case in the same scope!

A variable should describe its content (you should understand what it is when you read the name, for example a list of students will not be named 'list' but 'students' or  'studentsList') AND you should avoid to have 2 variables with the exact same name in the same scope (if you have to start doing something like `this.myvariable = myvariable` it means something is wrong in your implementation).

**2** Manage your title differently

What you want is the name + a status depending on if present or not.

So when you do that:

```
listItems.get(position).setTitle("");
```

you just loose the name as listItems and listitems are the exact same list.

So I'd suggest to have a `getName()` method on `RecyclerItem` to return the name. Remove the `set/getTitle` ones.

Then you manage the present/absent with a boolean.
Basically, like that:

```
if (signUpModeActive = true) {
    signUpModeActive = false;
    item.setIsPresent(false);
} else {
    signUpModeActive = true;
    item.setIsPresent(true);
}
```

It means you need to add a `setIsPresent` method to the `RecyclerItem`.

Then you, in the `onBindViewHolder` you do:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    RecyclerItem item = mListItems.get(position);

    String name = item.getName();
    String status = item.isPresent() ? "present" : "absent";
    String title = name + " " + status;

    holder.txtTitle.setText(title);
}
```

It'd be even better to use a string resource with a placeholder to manage the text of the status.